# Window.Open to open new tab with loading icon in body

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, document-ready

I am calling MVC Action method to load view on window.open but I want very first thing to be a loader before view loads. I tried this but this takes some time and shows blank page and after sometimes it shows loader icon. The loading icon should be the first thing in tab.

```
 document.onreadystatechange = function () {
        var state = document.readyState;
        if (state == 'interactive') {
            showLoader();
        }
        else if (state == 'complete') {
            hideLoader();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check my answer below.

Comment: Do you call action method by Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('.gif_loader_image').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

```css
body{
  background: url(http://www.banneredge.com/images/portfolio.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.gif_loader_image{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 1001;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  text-align:center;
}
.gif_loader_image img{
  width:30px;
  margin-top:40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gif_loader_image">
  <img src="https://media0.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/200_s.gif" alt="Loader..."/>
</div>
<div class="background_image_div"></div>
```

Using jQuery you can do it like this. By default show the loader and when document is ready simply hide the loader.